# Facebook page plugin not working when logging in using incognito

Tags: bigcommerce

How to fix facebook page plugin when using incognito? The problem is when i'm trying to login on messages tab using incognito mode it is just redirecting to timeline tab and no console error appearing.

Comment: hey @dev is this with the facebook plugin on wordpress? Do you have any additional information on what you mean by facebook plugin (meaning, if not the wordpress plugin), and what is not working with it?

Comment: hey @HeatherBarr No, I'm using bigcommerce and I add the codes I got here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/ to the html file of bigcommerce. The problem is when i'm on a normal browser the login on facebook page login is working but when i'm using incognito mode, there is still login button showing even im already login on facebook. It says I still need to login. here is a screenshot of it https://imgur.com/58GZCYp

Comment: Hey @dev, to clarify, you logged in when using your traditional browser and are now noticing when you try in an incognito browser that you have to log in again?

If this is correct, then that is expected behavior. Incognito does not have the cookies stored from your other browser, therefore you are being prompted to log in again.

Comment: hey @HeatherBarr, no, i'm already logged in on facebook using incognito but it still says i need to login and when i clicked the login button, it is not working like on a normal browser. Nothing happens when i'm clicking it

Comment: I'm posting on behalf of Andres, due to StackOverflow's point rules on commenting. His response is ---

This is Andres, I am one of the Developer Advocates with BigCommerce. I was able to reproduce the situation that you outlined and this looks like something that you will need to reach out to the Facebook/Google Chrome teams about since the issue is not stemming from the BigCommerce platform itself. It’s more related to how Chrome’s incognito handles it’s cookies during those sessions. Also when I click the login button it does open up a popup window prompting for login information.